# Show dots for incomplete data in a cell which is using cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-grid

If data doesn't fit the cell, usually `ui-grid` displays `dots` to tell that there are  more data available which can be seen on expanding the column.

But when I use the `cellTemplate`, it doesn't displays `dots` even if data doesn't fit. Please see attached screenshot for more information.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to how fix this problem.

Comment: Can you add your code in Fiddle/Plnkr?

Comment: ook..let me try..give me 10 mins..

Comment: Here is my plunkr.. the column where I dont use celltemplate shows correctly dots if it doesn't fit the cell.. but when I use template, it just wrap to new line.. How to fix that? http://plnkr.co/edit/TDX5jtPord1hkzCVaw3L?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using class="ui-grid-cell-contents" in your template?

Comment: no. please refer my plunkr for more info: http://plnkr.co/edit/TDX5jtPord1hkzCVaw3L?p=preview

Comment: '<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\"> {{COL_FIELD}} "        "{{COL_FIELD}}  </div';

Comment: Awesome...  @Raghu Reddy.. tahnks for your help.. I think it will solve my purpose.. let me integrate this to my original app. I was unaware of this class (ui-grid-cell-contents)